# forEach method is not work with string (character array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

The string is a collection of characters, which means the string is character array. I want to do some operation with every character of a string with `forEach()` method. But it does not work. 
      If I use a normal array then `forEach()` work but when I use it with string it does't work. But Why?

String (character's array)...

```html
<html>
 <p id="show"></p>
 <script>
   var name = "Raktim";
   var str = "";
   name.forEach(foo);
   function foo(value)
     {
        str += value;
     }
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = str
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is simple,  because there is no `String.prototype.forEach()` and  a string *is not* an array

Comment: So you would need to do something like `name.split('').forEach()`

Comment: @CodeManiac but string means character's array. `str = "Raktim"` will store like str[0] ='R', str[1] ='a', str[2] ='k' ...

Comment: `forEach()` isn't available on strings, but `Object.values(name).forEach(foo);` can be used to iterate the string to access each character. Make this change and your code will work as expected.

Comment: No, `String` does not mean _character array_, but you can access a string's character using `string[#]`

Comment: The bottom line is this: no matter how much you think a string is like a character array, JavaScript does not agree with you. **There is no `.forEach()` method for strings.**

Comment: It has length, and you can use index to access characters...but it still is not an array

Comment: Okay I understand, actually in C/C++ theory string are treat like character array.  But JS doesn't mean that...okay

Comment: Another conversion is use `Array.from(name)` or use spread `[...name].forEach()`

Comment: To be clear, String has [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), So, you can use any of the iteration protocols(Spread operator[...str],str[0], for...of), just that `.forEach()` function isn't present on the string's prototype. But array's forEach uses Symbol.iterator to iterate over the Array/ any other object that provides [Symbol.iterator]

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks, now it is clear for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without conversion to array, You can use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call a array method prototype on a string

```html
<html>
 <p id="show"></p>
 <script>
   var name = "Raktim";
   var str = "";
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(name, foo);//use array's forEach on a string 
   function foo(value)
     {
        str += " " + value;
     }
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = str
 </script>
</html>
```

To be clear, `String` has [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), So, you can use any of the iteration protocols(Spread operator[...str],str[0], for...of), but `.forEach()` function isn't present on the string's prototype. But array's forEach uses `Symbol.iterator` to iterate over the Array/any other object that provides `[Symbol.iterator]`

Answer (score 2):

You should convert the string into an array.

```
<html>
  <p id="show"></p>
  <script>
    var name = "Raktim";
    var str = "";
    var array = name.split("");
    array.forEach(element => {
      str += element;
    });
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = str;
  </script>
</html>
```